# What is the use of component without VOB (Clearcase UCM)?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I was told to create component in UCM.

How would you explain a difference between component and VOB to a beginner?

Also It asks two option.

Components in VOB and Components without VOB.

What is the use of having Component without VOB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have a Vob involved with a Component.
A Vob is the database (file-based database, not an SQL-based) containing all versions of all elements (files and directories).
Not to be mixed with a PVob, which is a special kind of Vob containing only UCM metadata (like the list of UCM projects, streams, components names, activities, ...).

You have two kinds of components, but each one is a coherent set of files:

- Vob component: the all Vob is a component.
- Root-based components: the component has its root in the **first directory level** of a Vob: `\aVob\aRoot`.

It is best to create root-based components (ie, several components per Vob), because each Vob you would create means several processes to manage it (`vob_server`, `vob_rpc`), and it becomes quite resource intensive quickly.
However, several components (even an hundred) within a Vob is not a problem.

But that means the name of your Vob must be "generic" enough to accommodate your components.

---

As for rootless components (with a PVob, but no Vob), see "[About rooted and rootless ClearCase UCM components](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21316953)".

> Rootless Components:
>
> - should NEVER be modifiable in a UCM environment.
> - are not associated with a data storage (vob-less)
> - are used to track changes from Other Components.
> - can contain dependency lists also known as a (Composite baseline Structure)
> - are tracked with baselines that have NO corresponding label type.
>
> Rootless Components should only be used to track the progress of Rooted Components.
>   Rootless component baselines should be used when rooted component dependencies are needed. The dependencies are rigid and can enforce a strict process once implemented.

See "[To create a composite baseline](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/t_cre_cmpst_bl.htm)" to see a rootless component in action.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler thank you for the edits, but I was still writing the answer, and was quite surprise when one of its section went missing ;)

Comment: Sorry - always a risk when there's no locking on the edits :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question is answered. VonC described two types of VOBs can be created, a single component VOB and multi-component VOB, to store the files. The question however is asking what's the use of creating a component w/o a VOB, one of the options when you create a component.

This type of rootless components are normally used to store the composite baseline. I am not aware of other usages.

I found this post because today I got an issue with my IIB projects. When loading dependency projects from another component, IIB toolkit will complain the dependency project is not from the same root directory (due to from different components in CC). This is really an IIB toolkit issue, but I am looking for a way to resolve this from CC.

Comment: Sure, my 5-years old answer was lacking on the rootless component side. I have edited/completed it accordingly.